# A Widget for displaying Facebook Streams of several Faceboom Pages

Tags: facebook, widget, facebook-social-plugins

i'm searching for a way to implement a Widget on my own Website, that displays recent Facebook-Posts from several Facebook Pages. Something like the Facebook Like-Box, but not only from ONE FB-Page, but from 30 to 40 FB-Pages.

Is there a Tool you can recommend to use?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know any tool for this, but it is quite easy to do this on your own with the Graph API. See this link for information and example code: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/page/feed